# Setting __proto__ on object without initial prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Let us create new object, and then change its prototype:

```
var obj = new Object;
obj.__proto__ = new Date;
obj.setTime // is a function
```

We see that `obj` now inherits properties from its new prototype, `new Date`.

Then, we create new object **without** prototype and change its prototype:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
obj.__proto__ = new Date;
obj.setTime // undefined
```

We see that prototype chain doesn't work - `obj` didn't inherit properties from `new Date`, even though its `__proto__` is `new Date`.

Why?

(I guess it's because `Object` has some internal logic in setter of `__proto__` property, but not sure)

Comment: When creating an object using `null` as prototype, there won't be `_proto__` set, since there's no prototype chain for the object at all. When you're setting `__proto__` manually, it becomes just a regular own property in the object. (`obj.__proto__.setTime` -> function)

Answer (score 2):

This is one subtle difference between `__proto__` and `Object.getPrototypeOf()` / `Object.setPrototypeOf()` when we need to explicitly access / modify the prototype of an object.

This is one of the reasons why i have convinced myself that we should use  `Object.setPrototypeOf()` and `Object.getPrototypeOf()` in the place of `__proto__`.

```js
var o = Object.create(null);
Object.setPrototypeOf(o, new Date());
console.log(o.setTime)
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) seems to be pretty convinced, that you shouldn't change the prototypes of objects at all.

Comment: @Teemu There are times you definitely need it for instance [array sub-classing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39653262/4543207) and array sub-classing is a beautiful thing if you want to have arrays with custom prototype methods without modifying the `Array.prototype` at all.

Comment: True, but I haven't seen much array sub-classing in the codes. Usually the Array prototype is just monkey-patched with joy. Kangax has written an [interesting arcticle](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) of the subject.

Comment: @Teemu Yes i had seen that article. And you are right; array sub-classing is  not a common practice. The point is pre ES6, array sub-classing was a hack done through `__proto__` and people instead just properly modified the `Array.prototype` through `Object.defineProperty()` But now my humble advise would be safely using array sub-classing for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var obj = Object.create(null);`, you create a object without a `__proto__`.

In the line after line, you simply created a field named `__proto__` and if you look closely that field itself will have an internal field called `__proto__`.

You can create any field with any names. In your case, you chose `__proto__` as the name of the field. It could have been anything.